# I have the same question, the question is not solved, and the available answers don't fit my needs

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I am writing to get your help in order to avoid posting a duplicate question.

I have the same problem reported here: [Using “and” instead of ampersand in natbib in-text citations (“\citet”)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186631/using-and-instead-of-ampersand-in-natbib-in-text-citations-citet)

The answers given are not satisfactory to me. The post is not solved (i.e., no answer has been selected by the OP as the right one, even when he himself has posted a solution for his problem).

So, my question is: how can I post my concerns to the questions given and add more information about the issue I need to be solved?

(1) Should I edit the initial question of the OP (by adding an 'EDIT' section)? This is what I would do if I were the OP and wanted to clarify why the answers given do not solve my problem.

(2) Should I, instead, add one comment in the question(s) given for now?

Comment: You ask a new question, explain clearly that your problem seems to be similar to the one you found (link to it!), show how you applied all the answers in your context and then explain why those outcomes don't meet your requirement (not satisfactory is not a good reason btw). Additionally show other options you tried. That should make your question not a duplicate.

Comment: I think this is better asked at the Meta of Tex.se. They can better judge if and how question can be made unique based on a specific context.

Comment: "This is what I would do if I were the OP and wanted to clarify why the answers given do not solve my problem." - If you were the author of the linked question, you also would have submitted an answer to your question, that I would presume answered your question (you don't typically submit a self-answer without a reason).  In this case, the author clearly doesn't know, they can accept their own answer. Their answer is clearly the answer they are willing to accept since they submitted the solution they, in the end, decided upon.

Comment: (Continued).....My point is only a new question, or a bounty requesting for a better answer, seems like the correct course of action, but you need a better reason the current answers don't answer your question.

Comment: You have enough rep there for a [bounty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/bounty), to attract more attention and hopefully answers.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you for the suggestion, but the only available answer (for now) together with all the comments contributed are clear enough to me. My LaTeX question is not different enough to post a new question. Therefore, for now, to me, the most reasonable choice seems to write new comments to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be editing the question to provide commentary on what you think of the answers.  This is true even if it's your own question.  The question is where you ask the question, not where you respond to answers.  If you want to commentate on a given answer, for example to indicate how it could be improved or how it might be problematic as an answer, post a comment under that answer.

Answer (score 3):

Usually it's not an *identical question* you have—otherwise the answer would have helped you. It's not like your wondering what's two plus two and there is another question that has an answer saying four.

First of all *link to the other question*. That shows you searched, you found the other question and your problem still persists. That's a big step from getting your question closed as a duplicate.

Secondly,  make clear any differences in the question. Any restrictions you have that weren't in the other question. Maybe the answer on the other question is a workaround that doesn't work for you because you need more precision or something like that. It may also be your environment that is different.

Thirdly, if there's a reasonably upvoted answer on the other question, describe why that answer doesn't apply to your problem. Why the solution doesn't work for you.